Find clusters with threshold for number of members
I need to find clusterization of some daily weather data,
and the number of days in any cluster should be more than some threshold  (e.g. 30).
So if some cluster has less members, it has to be merged with other (or the algorithm has to run again).
I learned almost all algorithms of clusterization (especially those that are used in Mathematica and Python' Skikit).
Number of clusters itself is not defined initially, so method should not be "KMeans" or "KMedoids".
Maybe I should write a special algorithm?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
